# Oracle Streams AQ. session.getQueue throwing AQOracleSQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: spring, stream, pooling, oracle-aq

Using Oracle Streams AQ in a multithreaded/multi-app environment I received an `AQOracleSQLException`: Exhausted Resultset after about 10 minutes of operation in one thread only.

```
oracle.AQ.AQOracleSQLException: Exhausted Resultset
        at oracle.AQ.AQOracleSession.getQueue(AQOracleSession.java:751)
        at au.com.xxx.queue.OracleQueue$$anonfun$2.apply(OracleQueue.scala:53)
```

The `AQOracleSession` is pooled via Spring as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MessageManagerDB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="aqSessionFactory" class="au.com.xxx.queue.AQSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="aqSessionTarget" factory-bean="aqSessionFactory" 
    factory-method="createAQSession" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="aqSessionPoolTargetSource" 
    class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="aqSessionTarget"/>
    <property name="maxSize" value="25"/>
</bean>

<bean id="aqSession" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSource" ref="aqSessionPoolTargetSource"/>
</bean>
```

With the factory method `createAQSession` being (in Scala):

```
def createAQSession = {
  val wasConnection = dataSource.getConnection.asInstanceOf[WSJdbcConnection]
  val connection = WSCallHelper.getNativeConnection(wasConnection).asInstanceOf[Connection]
  SessionWithConnection(AQDriverManager.createAQSession(connection), connection)
  // SessionWithConnection is just a case class akin to 
  // Tuple2[AQOracleSession, Connection]
}
```

The exception was thrown from the final line of the this block:

```
def sessionAndConnection = {
  applicationContext.getBean("aqSession").asInstanceOf[SessionWithConnectionI]
}

def write(category: String, relatedId: Option[String], payload: String): Array[Byte] = {
  val (session, conn) = {
    val sc = sessionAndConnection
    (sc.session, sc.connection)
  }
  val queueDef = dao.queueForWriting(category, relatedId).map{_.name}
  val queue = queueDef.map{name => session.getQueue("QUSR", name)}
```

Obviously, I am not directly handling the `ResultSet` used within `AQOracleSession`.

I *am* using the `Connection` associated with the `Session`, but this is not until later in the same method, and so can't be at fault here:

```
val clob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, true, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION)
```

Is it possible that the pooling config is not correct and there was some concurrent operations on the same session? There was nothing unusual in the other logs at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a defect with the v10 driver, which I was using by mistake. v11 RDBMS driver does not have this problem.